# How to access the values of a serialized multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hi I got this function:

```
public static function consumeMessage($xml, $debug = 1) {
    $xml = stripslashes(urldecode($xml));
    $rq = OpenPayU::parseOpenPayUDocument($xml);    

    $msg = $rq['OpenPayU']['OrderDomainRequest'];

    switch (key($msg)) {
        case 'OrderNotifyRequest':
            return OpenPayU_Order::consumeNotification($xml);
            break;
        case 'ShippingCostRetrieveRequest':
            return OpenPayU_Order::consumeShippingCostRetrieveRequest($xml);
            break;
        default:
            return key($smg);
            break;
    }
}
```

which I calling like this:

```
$result = OpenPayU_Order::retrieve($result->sessionId);
```

And write to file in this way:

```
write_to_file("debug.txt", "order details: \n\n " .
serialize($result->response) . "\n\n");
```

In the output I got:

> a:1:{s:8:"OpenPayU";a:2:{s:14:"HeaderResponse";a:3:{s:10:"SenderName";s:8:"checkout";s:7:"Version";s:3:"1.0";s:9:"Algorithm";s:3:"MD5";}s:19:"OrderDomainResponse";a:1:{s:21:"OrderRetrieveResponse";a:8:{s:5:"ResId";s:32:"28444ffd9de5489e08a32e6cd51274a5";s:6:"Status";a:1:{s:10:"StatusCode";s:16:"OPENPAYU_SUCCESS";}s:13:"MerchantPosId";s:5:"37857";s:9:"SessionId";s:32:"55a6d45cc0fef40ce95e9c1321b19b13";s:14:"CustomerRecord";a:6:{s:10:"CustomerId";s:8:"nyi3iw6v";s:5:"Email";s:28:"netprofile@netprofile.com.pl";s:5:"Phone";s:15:"(+48)
>   786265656";s:9:"FirstName";s:5:"mieta";s:8:"LastName";s:5:"mieta";s:8:"Language";s:2:"pl";}s:11:"OrderStatus";s:20:"ORDER_STATUS_PENDING";s:12:"CurrencyCode";s:3:"PLN";s:7:"PayType";s:1:"t";}}}}

But I need get almost every value sepateted, f.ex: 'StatusCode' and save it to database, is there any way to get it without regular expressions?

I trying get it like $result->response['statuscode']; but I get nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to unserialize the string from file, do

```
$array = unserialize(file_get_contents('/path/to/file'));
```

This will give you the array that was in `$result->response`, which you can access like any other multidimensional array, e.g.

```
$responseData = $result->response;
echo $responseData["OpenPayU"]["HeaderResponse"]["SenderName"];
…
```

If you don't know how to access a multidimensional array, [please refer to the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.array.php).

Comment: @ariel you have to be more specific. what is the problem?

Comment: How to get f.ex this value: 'StatusCode' which is: OPENPAYU_SUCCESS